# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Guid' to type 'System.String' Whilst I am only using Guid

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-identity, blazor

I am trying to get an object of type 'DocumentationPage' out of my database with the following function:

```cs
CurrentDocumentationPage = await documentationPageService.GetDocumentationPageById(DocumentID);
```

in this case I am using

```cs
[Parameter] public Guid DocumentID { get; set; }
```

This gets passed along with a `NavigateTo` function

```cs
public void OnNavItemClick(Guid Id)
        {
            navMan.NavigateTo($"/View/" + Id);
        }
```

To get this with the corresponding Guid out of my database.
My `DocumentationPage` class looks like the following:

```cs
public class DocumentationPage : Entity
    {
        public string UserId { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Content { get; set; }
        public DateTime Published { get; set; }
        public DateTime Updated { get; set; }
    }
```

Where Entity is:

```cs
public class Entity
    {
        public Guid Id;
    }
```

Now the following should happen:

- Click NavMenu item which holds an `Guid ID` to pass along in the `OnClick` function.
- Fires the function with the ID that has passed along:

```cs
CurrentDocumentationPage = await documentationPageService.GetDocumentationPageById(DocumentID);
```

- After that it reaches the method:

```cs
public async Task<DocumentationPage> GetByIdAsync(Guid id)
        {
            DocumentationPage documentationPage = context.DocumentationPages.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == id);

            return documentationPage;
        }
```

Which at that point prompts me with the error
`Unable to cast object of type 'System.Guid' to type 'System.String`

When theres no point I am trying to use it as a string.

This is my stacktrace:

```
  HResult=0x80004002
  Message=Unable to cast object of type 'System.Guid' to type 'System.String'.
  Source=System.Private.CoreLib
  StackTrace:
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CastHelpers.ChkCast_Helper(Void* toTypeHnd, Object obj)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlBuffer.get_String()
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetString(Int32 i)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Single[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.Execute[TResult](Expression query)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
   at System.Linq.Queryable.First[TSource](IQueryable`1 source)
   at TerceraDeveloperSite.Repositories.DocumentationPageRepository.<GetByIdAsync>d__2.MoveNext() in C:\Users\Rowin\source\repos\TerceraDeveloperSite\Repositories\DocumentationPageRepository.cs:line 21

  This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
    [External Code]
    TerceraDeveloperSite.Repositories.DocumentationPageRepository.GetByIdAsync(System.Guid) in DocumentationPageRepository.cs
```

Now, I did find
`at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetString(Int32 i)`
which wouldn't make sense either way, but as far as I know I'm not changing anything regarding the SqlDataReader.

It just doesn't make sense to me as why it has problems with this method.

Comment: It's coming from `GetString` on the `SqlDataReader`, which suggests to me that it has already processed the query and started receiving the result. Could it perhaps be one of your properties (`UserId` for example)?

Comment: Oh my lord, sometimes I'm wondering if I can even code. Id never have thought about that. Thanks a lot for giving me that insight. This got solved really fast. @Llama

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answer was given by Llama,
My database was set up for `UserID` to be a `Guid`.
But in my `DocumentationPage` class it was a `string` instead of `Guid`